# QPJ files are not generated

Tags: qgis, shapefile, esri-geodatabase, prj

[image]

QPJ files are not generated. QGIS version is 3.301. Save file ESRI shapefile.

Comment: What are you using the shapefiles for? Do they open in QGIS? Some info here: What is a QPJ file?
A QPJ file is a GIS map projection file created by QGIS, an open-source, cross-platform GIS application. It contains the coordinate reference system (CRS) and map projection used to transform a 3D representation of the Earth into a 2D plane. QPJ files are similar to the PRJ map projection files used by other GIS systems, but QPJ files contain QGIS-specific data.
(from https://fileinfo.com/extension/qpj)